# Which scripture claims to be essence of all Aranyakas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, philosophy

Each Veda has been [subclassified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas) into four major text parts – the Samhitas, the Aranyakas, the Brahmanas, and the Upanishads.

Now,

- Essence of all Samhitas  --> compiled as **Devata Kanda Sutras**
- Essence of all Brahmanas --> compiled as **Purva Mimansa Sutras** by  Vyasa's students Jaimini
- Essence of all Upanishads --> compiled as **Brahma Sutras** (Vedanta sutras) by Vedvyasa

Now, my question is that, **which** scripture claims to be essence of all **Aaranyakas** ?

Comment: I think Jaimini's Purva Mimansa Sutra also constitutes the philosophical interpretation of Yajnas and hence Aranyaka.